# How to record audio on my Xamarin.iOS app with OPUS format?

Tags: ios, xcode, audio, xamarin.ios, opus

Are there any samples for recording audio with the OPUS format?

I am using the OPUS format as it will record good quality audio with a small size. I have downloaded the OPUS Xamarin library but I'm not able to find a tutorial or any sample code.

All I found this piece of code :

`AudioStream.RegisterCodec("opus", 48000, 2, () => { return new OpusCodec(); }, true);`

I don't know how to added to my recording sample. I'm using `AVAudioRecorder`

Comment: Is this the component your using https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/icelinkcommunity ?

Comment: Yes, that's the same component I'm using, i just need to know how to combine along with AVAudioRecorder to get it the OPUS format.